# Optimisation of LinqToXml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Could anyone tell me if this is correct or if there's a faster/cleaner way to do it?

```
//I load p as a xDoc so I can use linq to xml
    XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(p);
    // retrieve each "Item" node except if orderedQuantity is 0 or name is "nullorderitem"
    IEnumerable<XElement> orderedRes = from item in myDoc.Descendants("Item")
                                       where ((double)item.Element("orderedQuantity") > 0 &&     item.Element("ResourceId").Name != "NULLOrderItem")
                                       select item;

    foreach (XElement xelem in orderedRes)
    {
        if(xelem.Element("Name").Value.ToLower() == "oneofmyvalueIneed" 
            || xelem.Element("Name").Value.ToLower() == "anotherone"
            || xelem.Element("Name").Value.ToLower() == "yetanother")
        {
            FieldProperties elem = new FieldProperties();
            elem.Fieldname = xelem.Element("Name").Value;
            elem.Fieldvalue = xelem.Element("OrderedQuantity").Value;
            lElem.Add(elem);
        }
    }
```

Knowing that lElem is a list of FieldProperties, and FieldProperties is a class looking like this :

```
FieldProperties
string fieldname
string fieldvalue
```

and p is a string that looks like

```
<items>
<item>
 <resourceid>blablabla</resourceid>
 <somerandomtag>whocares</somerandomtag>
 <orderedquantity>0.0</orderedquantity>
</item>
<item>
 <resourceid>oneofmyvalueIneed</resourceid>
 <somerandomtag>whocares</somerandomtag>
 <orderedquantity>1.0</orderedquantity>
</item>
<item>
 <resourceid>yetanother</resourceid>
 <somerandomtag>whocares</somerandomtag>
 <orderedquantity>0.0</orderedquantity>
</item>
</items>
```

Comment: This part doesn't make sense: `item.Element("ResourceId").Name != "NULLOrderItem")`. Name is always `ResourceId`, it will always return `true`. Did you mean `Value`?

Comment: This probably belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There's nothing really wrong with this (other than the mistake I pointed out). I'd probably project the XML to your object *first*, and then filter afterwards (as the filtering would then be a little easier).

Comment: Charles Mager ==> Totally right about value. Stupid mistake.

Also, sorry bout posting it in wrong part, didn't know there even was a code review section, still new user.

But I don't get what you mean by "project your xml first then filter", isn't that what I do? 


€dit = ok, seen the below answer I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the `if` statement by using the `.Contains` method.

```
var validNames = new List<string> {"oneofmyvalueIneed","anotherone","yetanother"}

XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(p);
var result = from item in myDoc.Descendants("Item")
      where ((double)item.Element("orderedQuantity") > 0 &&                   
            item.Element("ResourceId").Name != "NULLOrderItem") && // See Charles's comment about this line
            validNames.Contains(iten.Element("Name").Value.ToLower())
      select item;

foreach (var item in orderedRes)
{
    FieldProperties elem = new FieldProperties();
    elem.Fieldname = xelem.Element("Name").Value;
    elem.Fieldvalue = xelem.Element("OrderedQuantity").Value;
    lElem.Add(elem);
}
```

Then you can also replace the `foreach` with

```
select new FieldProperties
{
    Fieldname = item.Element("Name").Value,
    Fieldvalue = xelem.Element("OrderedQuantity").Value
};
```

Adding it all together + some optimization when accessing the child elements it would look like:

```
var validNames = new List<string> {"oneofmyvalueIneed","anotherone","yetanother"}

XDocument myDoc = XDocument.Parse(p);
var result = from item in myDoc.Descendants("Item")
      let value = item.Element("orderedQuantity")
      let name = iten.Element("Name").Value.ToLower()
      where ((double)value > 0 &&                   
            item.Element("ResourceId").Name != "NULLOrderItem") && // See Charles's comment about this line
            validNames.Contains(name)
      select new FieldProperties
      {
          Fieldname = name
          Fieldvalue = value
      };
```

Comment: @CharlesMager - ops true :) stupid mistake. Correcting

Comment: Thanks! For validity of your answer for next viewer, you might want to edit the foreach clause : item ==> xelem (or replace xelem by item in the loop)

Perfect answer, 10/10 thank you :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I can go f*ck myself since I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: but how is the field properties added to the list, in the last version? You create a new fieldproperties, but you don't do anything with it ?

Comment: @DoctorPrisme - If you create this list and fill it just with the items from this linq then just replace the `result` with that list and add `ToList()` at the end of the select. If you have a list and want to add to it also these items then use: `lElem,AddRange(result);`

Comment: I will assume it's lElem.AddRange(result) 
however, may I ask why "addrange" instead of "add" ? :)

Comment: @DoctorPrisme - `Add` inserts 1 item into the list at the last position. `AddRange` adds a collection of items. `result` is of type `IEnumerable<FieldProperties>` so instead of adding another `foreach` loop and adding them one by one better use `AddRange`

Comment: you're awesome.
"however" (yeah) I have a last remark :
sice fieldvalue is a string, and value is a double, you should add a ".toString()" in your answer ;-)

Thanks a lot man :)